# How can I adjust the output of an article using PKB

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, visualforce-template

I am building a site using the PKB package, and need to adjust the output markup of articles. Currently this markup is all built with tables, but after searching through every class, component, and page, have not been able to find the content.

I know that the content is called from within pkb_articleview.component, but can't trace it from there.

Answer (score 0):

By using the article [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=knowledge_article_templates_custom.htm&language=en_US) I was able to create a custom template/vf page for each Article Type in knowledge. Once I had these templates created it was as simple as using API calls to retrieve the data I wanted.

```
<h1>{!ArticleType.Title}</h1>
<div class="article-content">
  {!ArticleType.Article__c}
</div>
```